# python - writing to existing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i'm new to coding, doing my assignment and i'm stuck. thanks in advance.

The question is

writeABFile()

The function should open the 'file.dat' for write access - overwriting the existing file

each row in 'file' varaible needs to be turned into a string of the following format:

8,8,8,8,8,8nl
8 represents the chair and should be set to character '0' (zero) if chair is available and the character '1' if the chair is booked. The 'nl' is a "new-line/carriage return"

use try and except statements

file.dat contains list of lists - [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]

my code is which i think i've messed up:

def writeABFile():

```
while not opened:
    try:
        openFile = open("file.dat", "w")

        for row in file:
            openFile.write(",".join(map(str(8,8,8,8,8,8,), row)) + "\n")

        openFile.close()
    except Exception:
        print("Failed to write to file.dat file")
    else:
        openFile.close()
```

Comment: What is exactly your doubt?

Comment: i'm doubting  openFile.write(",".join(map(str(8,8,8,8,8,8,), row)) + "\n"). it's not doing what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hint: What are you expecting to get from map(str(8,8,8,8,8,8,), row)?

The `map` function takes a list and a function, and applies the function to each element of the list.

Did you mean `map(row,str)` perhaps?

Try printing the result of your `map` construction to the screen first, and see if it is what you want.

#### Another tip, although nothing to do with your problem, is to use `with`

This allows you to not have to remember to close it, even in the case of errors.

```
    try:
        with open("file.dat", "w") as openFile:
            for row in file:
                openFile.write("...........\n")
    except Exception:
        print("Failed to write to file.dat file")
```